# brew install specific version of library and specific dependencies

Tags: homebrew

I have an issue with a package, `dmtx-utils`, that was moved to the `homebrew/boneyard`. It is actually expecting, what I believe is to be an *older* version of `ImageMagick`; something predating 7.0.4-8 (which is the current version).

In the process of installing the various other needed packages for our workflow, we also install `zbar` - which is also dependent on `ImageMagick`.

When installing `zbar` via `brew install zbar` it will also install the dependent `ImageMagick`, but in doing so, the latest version of `ImageMagick`.

In this case: When installing `zbar`, how can I make `brew install` a specific version of its dependencies, like `ImageMagick`?

Or more generally: When installing `package X`, how can I make `brew install` a specific version of its dependencies, like `package Y`?

Thanks and best,

Sander

Comment: Install the dependency first, and [pick the version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4158763/238978) in doing so.

Comment: So even though I do this (first install `ImageMagick` via `brew install imagemagick@6` - indeed I need a specific version), `brew install zbar` will install the dependencies. In this case `ImageMagick` version 7. How can I make it not do that? Also: `zbar` hasn't changed between version 6 and 7 of ImageMagick - as far as I can tell at least...

Comment: Had the same issue -- installing a previous version doesn't satisfy the dependency check. Really frustrating. I don't think homebrew's concept of versions is fined grained enough

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to do this at the moment is this:

1. Install the dependencies, `packages Y`, first, and `pin` all the of them whose
   versions you care about.
2. Install the final `package X`, and brew will attempt to
   install the latest it can (given what brew is hosting currently and the versions of the previous dependencies).

However, this supposedly simple two-step process is fraught with issues due to how Brew works, which transforms the real problem you want to answer into *how do you install any arbitrary version of a package?*

Doing this is answered in Emil's shared link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula/4158763#4158763), which is another Stack Overflow question.